# Removing extra space in Search View Icon in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working on customizing Android Actionbar in API level 11 and above. I have a custom view for Actionbar in which i have a SearchView widget with other icons. But when the search view is in icon shape(not in expanded form) it takes more than desired space(as shown in red below).

[image]

If i change my icon to a black image the following result is shown:

[image]

I have gone through the xml layout of the search view and have tried to reduce this padding by accessing individual views inside search view but the space does not get removed. The code i have written for the same is as below

```
 searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    searchView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
    searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    searchPlate.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    int searchTextId = searchPlate.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    final TextView searchText = (TextView) searchPlate.findViewById(searchTextId);

    searchText.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    searchText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
    ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);
```

Can we do this by any means? I have noticed one thing that the search view xml layout uses padding.Can that be the reason for this?

I have seen lot of post for customizing Actionbar and search view but no one answers my question exactly.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be your search icon image have more width and height. Open you image in any image editing tool like photoshop and see the image size and try to reduce the image width and height as well as the image looks perfect.

**Update:**
I think the reason behind this issue is the default value of android:minWidth for the ActionBar buttons or icons which is 56dip , so you need to change it.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Thanks for replying but please see my updated post , when i change the icon to complete black image the gap is still there. So my image is much smaller than the area.

Comment: Check my updated answer may be it is the reson of your problem.

Comment: Thanks..you are welcome..please mark it as right answer so that it can help others too.